# How to plot a simple double matrix into TableView in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I want to create a simple `TableView` in JavaFX where my data is a 2d-array  like `double[][]` matrix, but I don't know how I can achieve this, some advice?

Comment: `new TableView<double[]>()`???

Comment: Yes,But how can I insert the array 2D into tableView? My matrix has 4 columns and 150 rows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Fabian suggests in comments:

1. Define your table as:

   ```
   TableView<double[]>
   ```
2. Add the elements of your `double[][]` array as items to the table (extracting elements from the `double[][]` and adding them to an `ObservableList<double[]>`).
3. Create columns for your table, providing a cell value factory for each.

   ```
   col.setCellValueFactory(param -> new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(param.getValue()[c]))
   ```

   where `c` is the column index.
4. If you need to format the cell items, also provide a [cell factory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.html#setCellFactory-javafx.util.Callback-).

[image: matrix]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class MatrixTable extends Application {
    private Random random = new Random(42);
    private static final int N_COLS = 4;
    private static final int N_ROWS = 100;
    private static final int MAX_DATA_VALUE = 100;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        ObservableList<double[]> data = generateData();

        TableView<double[]> table = new TableView<>(data);
        table.getColumns().setAll(createColumns());
        table.setPrefSize(200, 250);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(table));
        stage.show();
    }

    private ObservableList<double[]> generateData() {
        return FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                IntStream.range(0, N_ROWS)
                        .mapToObj(r ->
                                IntStream.range(0, N_COLS)
                                        .mapToDouble(c -> randomValue())
                                        .toArray()
                        ).collect(Collectors.toList())
        );
    }

    private List<TableColumn<double[], Double>> createColumns() {
        return IntStream.range(0, N_COLS)
                .mapToObj(this::createColumn)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private TableColumn<double[], Double> createColumn(int c) {
        TableColumn<double[], Double> col = new TableColumn<>("C" + (c + 1));
        col.setCellValueFactory(param -> new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(param.getValue()[c]));

        return col;
    }

    private long randomValue() {
        return Math.round(random.nextDouble() * MAX_DATA_VALUE  * 100) / 100.0;
    }
}
```

> Can you explain me this line code?
>
> ```
> col.setCellValueFactory(param -> new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(param.getValue()[c]))
> ```

From the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.html#cellValueFactoryProperty):

> The cell value factory needs to be set to specify how to populate all cells within a single TableColumn. A cell value factory is a Callback that provides a TableColumn.CellDataFeatures instance, and expects an ObservableValue to be returned.

So what it is doing is defining a way to extract the data for the column from the `double[]` array of data for the row (which has been provided by `param.getValue()`).  Because we are using a [ReadOnlyObjectWrapper](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.html) around the data value, if you made the table cell editable (which I did not do in this sample), it would not write back the edited value to the array.  The wrapper is necessary to convert the double data value to an ObservableValue (as required by the cell factory interface).

Yeah, I know it is confusing, but that is the price paid to allow TableViews to efficiently be backed by potentially millions of data items as [virtualized controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995444/what-are-virtualized-controls-mentioned-in-javafx-documentation).  If you don't need the virtualization features and other features of a TableView, you could always just use labels in a [GridPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html) instead.

Comment: Thanks for your solution to help me! 
Observing your code, I've done a simple [Solution](http://pastebin.com/WHyxTs4a) (I'm a Java beginner developer) where I'm using an ArrayList<Double> like double[]. 
Can you explain me this line code? 
`col.setCellValueFactory(param -> new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(param.getValue()[c]))`