# TableView Cell updateItem not called for cells outside the viewport

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I have made my own selection column, and in the column header I have a checkbox that when I click on changes the value of the cell I have set for the cellValueFactory which triggers the method updateItem in the TableCell which fires a custom event that I need to work with.

```
public abstract class GeneratedPersistableBeanFX extends GeneratedPersistableBean {

private static CheckBox select_all;

public GeneratedPersistableBeanFX(int beanState) {
    super(beanState);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
private BooleanProperty SelectedInGridProperty = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);

public BooleanProperty selectedInGridProperty() {
    return SelectedInGridProperty;
}

public Boolean getSelectedInGrid() {
    return SelectedInGridProperty.getValue();
}

public void setSelectedInGrid(Boolean val) {
    SelectedInGridProperty.setValue(val);
}

public static CustomTableColumn<GeneratedPersistableBeanFX, Boolean> getTableColumnSelectedInGrid(String columnName) {
    getSelectAllCheckBox();

    String columnHeader = ((columnName == null) ? "Selected" : columnName);
    CustomTableColumn<GeneratedPersistableBeanFX, Boolean> theCol = new CustomTableColumn<>(columnHeader);
    theCol.setId(columnHeader);
    theCol.setMinWidth(32);
    theCol.setColumnName(columnHeader);
    theCol.setGraphic(getSelectAllCheckBox());
    theCol.setStyle("-fx-alignment: CENTER;");
    theCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().selectedInGridProperty());
    theCol.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<GeneratedPersistableBeanFX, Boolean>, TableCell<GeneratedPersistableBeanFX, Boolean>>() {
        @Override
        public TableCell<GeneratedPersistableBeanFX, Boolean> call(TableColumn<GeneratedPersistableBeanFX, Boolean> col) {

            final TableCell<GeneratedPersistableBeanFX, Boolean> cell = new TableCell<GeneratedPersistableBeanFX, Boolean>() {

                @Override
                public void updateItem(Boolean item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    setText(null);
                    // setMinHeight(40);
                    if (item == null) {
                        setGraphic(null);
                    }
                    else {
                        if (item.booleanValue() && getGraphic() == null) {
                            setGraphic(CustomImageLoaderFX.getInstance().getImageView("check.png", 16));
                        }
                        else if (item.booleanValue() && getGraphic() != null) {
                            getGraphic().setVisible(true);
                        }
                        else if (getGraphic() != null) {
                            getGraphic().setVisible(false);
                        }
                        if (getTableView() != null && getTableRow() != null && item != null) {
                            getTableView().fireEvent(
                                    new CustomTableColumnSelectionChangedEvent((GeneratedPersistableBeanFX) getTableRow().getItem(), item.booleanValue()));
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            cell.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                    ObservableValue<Boolean> ov = ((TableCell<GeneratedPersistableBeanFX, Boolean>) event.getSource()).getTableColumn()
                            .getCellObservableValue(((TableCell<GeneratedPersistableBeanFX, Boolean>) event.getSource()).getIndex());
                    SimpleBooleanProperty sp = (SimpleBooleanProperty) ov;
                    if (sp == null) {
                        return;
                    }
                    GeneratedPersistableBeanFX bean = (GeneratedPersistableBeanFX) ((TableCell<GeneratedPersistableBeanFX, Boolean>) event.getSource())
                            .getTableRow().getItem();
                    if (sp.getValue() == false) {
                        sp.setValue(true);
                    }
                    else {
                        sp.setValue(false);
                    }
                }
            });
            return cell;
        }

    });
    return theCol;
}

public static CheckBox getSelectAllCheckBox() {
    if (select_all == null) {
        select_all = new CheckBox();
        select_all.setOnAction(e -> selectAllBoxes(e));
    }
    return select_all;
}

private static void selectAllBoxes(ActionEvent e) {
    CustomTableView<GeneratedPersistableBeanFX> table = getTableViewFromCheckBox(((CheckBox) e.getSource()).getParent());
    ObservableList<GeneratedPersistableBeanFX> items = table.getItems();
    for (GeneratedPersistableBeanFX item : items) {
        item.setSelectedInGrid(((CheckBox) e.getSource()).isSelected());
        //What I tried to force to trigger updateItem on all rows
        table.getColumns().get(0).setVisible(false);
        table.getColumns().get(0).setVisible(true);
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static CustomTableView<GeneratedPersistableBeanFX> getTableViewFromCheckBox(Parent parent) {
    if (parent instanceof CustomTableView<?>) {
        return (CustomTableView<GeneratedPersistableBeanFX>) parent;
    }
    else if (parent != null && parent.getParent() != null) {
        return getTableViewFromCheckBox(parent.getParent());
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

For example I have a JME 3D window imbedded in a Dialog that shows the 3D Models of materials and there is also a tableview with all the materials. When I click on select all only the materials visible in the tableview viewport are being highlighted in my 3D and as I scroll down it has the funny behaviour that the remaining materials get highlighted as I scroll down.

**Problem is, the method updateItem is only called for cells currently visible in the TableViews viewport.**

Is there any way to circumvent this behaviour and make it call for every single cell of every item in the list regardless of visibility?

Comment: Post your `GeneratedPersistableBeanFX` class (at least the parts relevant to the `selectedInGridProperty`).

Comment: Done, altough I really think its down to javafx behaviour rather than code. Noticed this behaviour too in other tableviews where we would color some materials in a table with css.And the last row would not get colored if it was say only 1/2 visible. Had to adjust the size of the tableview so that the rows fit perfectly. Altough that may be a down to css, here its strictly value related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I read up a bit on the issue, and found out that the problem I had was because a TableView amongst others, uses virtualized cells,which are explained better [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995444/what-are-virtualized-controls-mentioned-in-javafx-documentation)

Basically one should never use the updateItem method to do anything logic related, its only recommended for changing the visuals of the cell.

With that in mind I simply moved the moment when I fired my event from the updateItem method to the user events clicking on the select all checkbox or clicking on the cell itself. Its not as neat but it works.

```
 private static void selectAllBoxes(ActionEvent e) {
    CustomTableView<GeneratedPersistableBeanFX> table = getTableViewFromCheckBox(((CheckBox) e.getSource()).getParent());
    if (table == null) {
        return;
    }
    ObservableList<GeneratedPersistableBeanFX> items = table.getItems();
    for (GeneratedPersistableBeanFX item : items) {
        item.setSelectedInGrid(((CheckBox) e.getSource()).isSelected());
        table.fireEvent(new CustomTableColumnSelectionChangedEvent(item, ((CheckBox) e.getSource()).isSelected()));
    }
}
 cell.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        SimpleBooleanProperty sp = (SimpleBooleanProperty) (((TableCell<GeneratedPersistableBeanFX, Boolean>) event.getSource())
            .getTableColumn().getCellObservableValue(((TableCell<GeneratedPersistableBeanFX, Boolean>) event.getSource()).getIndex()));
        if (sp == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (sp.getValue() == false) {
            sp.setValue(true);
        }
        else {
            sp.setValue(false);
        }
        ((TableCell<GeneratedPersistableBeanFX, Boolean>) event.getSource()).getTableView().fireEvent(
            new CustomTableColumnSelectionChangedEvent((GeneratedPersistableBeanFX) ((TableCell<GeneratedPersistableBeanFX, Boolean>) event
            .getSource()).getTableRow().getItem(), sp.getValue().booleanValue()));

    }
});
```

A weekend away from coding and work can sometimes do wonders! I just didnt realize this at all on Fr.