# JavaFX - Memory Consumption

Tags: memory, javafx

I have a huge JavaFX application that mostly uses FXML files to create the views, i noticed high memory usage but have been ignoring it for a while. After investigation i found that every single view is consuming a lot, however, after closing the form garbage collector does the job and used memory is released. 
For example, scrolling throw a table view that has approx. 1000 elements [screen shot attached], the memory usage spikes from 350 MB to 780 MB,,

[image: Table View]
[image: Table View Memory Consumption]

The exact same happens on scrolling throw a list view that shows the same data of the table view :

[image: List View]
[image: List View Memory Consumption]

the question is,, is that normal? or i maybe doing something wrong

**UPDATE**

For table view i am doing the following to generate a column:

```
public static <T> TableColumn<T, T> generateGraphicColumn(String title, Callback<TableColumn<T, T>, TableCell<T, T>> callback) {
    TableColumn<T, T> column = generateColumn(title, null);
    column.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<T, T>, ObservableValue<T>>() {

        @Override
        public ObservableValue<T> call(CellDataFeatures<T, T> param) {
            SimpleObjectProperty<T> s = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
            s.setValue(param.getValue());
            return s;
        }
    });
    column.setCellFactory(callback);
    return column;
}

public static <T> TableColumn<T, T> generateGraphicColumn(String title, Callback<TableColumn<T, T>, TableCell<T, T>> callback, double width) {

    TableColumn<T, T> column = generateGraphicColumn(title, callback);
    column.setMaxWidth(width);
    column.setMinWidth(width);
    return column;

}
public static <T,S> TableColumn<T, S> generateColumn(String title,
        Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<T, S>, ObservableValue<S>> propertyValueFactory) {

    TableColumn<T, S> column;
    column = new TableColumn<>();
    if (propertyValueFactory != null)
        column.setCellValueFactory(propertyValueFactory);
    column.setStyle(column.getStyle() + "-fx-alignment: BASELINE_CENTER;");
    column.setText(title);
    return column;

}
```

and i am using code above as following:

```
    { // status
        TableColumn<Visit, Visit> column = TableViewUtilities.generateGraphicColumn(text("General.STATUS"),
                new Callback<TableColumn<Visit, Visit>, TableCell<Visit, Visit>>() {
                    @Override
                    public TableCell<Visit, Visit> call(final TableColumn<Visit, Visit> param) {
                        final TableCell<Visit, Visit> cell = new TableCell<Visit, Visit>() {

                            @Override
                            public void updateItem(Visit item, boolean empty) {

                                super.updateItem(item, empty);


                                if (empty || getIndex() < 0) {
                                    setGraphic(null);
                                    setText(null);
                                    return;
                                }

                                item = getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex());

                                Label label = new Label();
                                StackPane pane = new StackPane(label);
                                pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                                label.setMaxWidth(10);
                                label.setMinWidth(10);
                                label.setMinHeight(30);

                                setText(item.getStatus().display());
                                String background = FXMLConstants .toHexString(ColorUtils.getVisitBackgroundColor(item));
                                pane.setStyle(String.format("-fx-background-color:%s;;", background));
                                setGraphic(pane);
                                setText(item.getStatus().display());
                                setStyle(getStyle() + "-fx-alignment: CENTER_LEFT;");
                            }
                        };
                        return cell;
                    }
                }, 100);

        column.setComparator(VisitCommonHelper.getCompByStatus());
        tblVisits.getColumns().add(column);
    }
```

Comment: This depends quite a lot on the data type of rows in the table, and the way you display them (custom Cell Factories). It is next to impossible to say if it is normal without more context (i.e. - the class used as data model and any Cell Factories used on the table).

Comment: @sillyfly kindly check the update, i added an example of how i am creating the columns of the table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a new `Label` and `StackPane` for every non-empty cell update, which may explain why the heap usage rises but may be garbage-collected.

You can try solving it by caching your node (`Label` in a `StackPane` in your case) - creating it only once:

```
final TableCell<Visit, Visit> cell = new TableCell<Visit, Visit>() {
    private Label label;
    private StackPane pane;
    {
        // This is the constructor of the anonymous class. Alternatively, you may choose to create the label and pane lazily the first time they're needed. 
        label = new Label();
        pane = new StackPane(label); 
        pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        label.setMaxWidth(10);
        label.setMinWidth(10);
        label.setMinHeight(30);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(Visit item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty || getIndex() < 0) {
            setGraphic(null);
            setText(null);
            return;
        }
        item = getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex());

        setText(item.getStatus().display());

        String background = FXMLConstants.toHexString(ColorUtils.getVisitBackgroundColor(item));
        pane.setStyle(String.format("-fx-background-color:%s;;", background));
        setGraphic(pane);
        setText(item.getStatus().display());
        setStyle(getStyle() + "-fx-alignment: CENTER_LEFT;");
    }
};
```

Also - what is the use of the label, if you never set its text? What is the `contentDisplay` of the cell? Are the nodes even shown?

Comment: your solution indeed solved the problem,, the label  was being used then i set the cell text instead [label will be removed],,,, one question thou,, why it will create a stack pane if i have an if statement that will return if the cell is empty?? Thank you very much

Comment: another question if you don't mind,,, a swing version of the same application uses 150 MB of the ram,, we revamped the UI only,, it now takes 350 MB,, does this mean i have bad design choices or FX graphics are just heavy

Comment: Swing and JavaFX can't be directly compared in terms of memory usage, as they are completely different toolkits. It is always possible there are other optimizations you can make, but you can't really compare the two.  As for why a new pane was created - you are correct that in cases of an empty cell no new pane would be created, but JavaFX `TableView` (as well as `ListView`, `TreeTableView` etc.) use "virtual nodes" - effectively re-using the same `Cell` for different items, so the `updateItem` method is called multiple times on scroll, as the item displayed in each cell changes.

Comment: See also this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995444/what-are-virtualized-controls-mentioned-in-javafx-documentation