# Lag when displaying many images in JavaFX GridPane

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I'm trying to display a bunch of images with JavaFX in a GridPane using constraints, and my code does show them perfectly. However, for some reason the images cause my stage to lag, despite my code working. Is there a way I could get around this?

For context, "arr" is a 2d ArrayList that I've made to have strings, and checkBoxList contains some checkboxes arranged in columns of around 40 each, with a spacing of 2 in between them.

```
public void setUpTypeImages()
{
  for (int p = 0; p < arr.size(); p++)
  {
     typesList.add(new ArrayList<ImageView>());
     for (int y = 0; y < arr.get(p).size(); y++)
     {  
        ImageView type = new ImageView("Types\\" + arr.get(p).get(y) + ".png");
        typesList.get(p).add(type);
        typesList.get(p).get(y).setFitWidth(30);
        typesList.get(p).get(y).setFitHeight(30);     
        GridPane.setConstraints(typesList.get(p).get(y), GridPane.getColumnIndex(checkBoxList.get(p)) + y + 1, GridPane.getRowIndex(checkBoxList.get(p))); 
        choiceLayout.getChildren().add(typesList.get(p).get(y));
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: hi, where is the image load call happening? I mean, the method in which things get printed. Is choiceLayout.getChildren().add(typesList.get(p).get(y)); the one that triggers a image to be updated?

Comment: @aran Yes, the line that you mentioned is the line that triggers each image to be shown. The functionality of it is perfect, but the issue arises from the lag it causes.

Comment: and the lag happens while loading, or once loaded? I mean, does it freeze even if all images are already loaded?

Comment: and the last question, is this an optional view? I mean, you only load the panel if you choose to (and then you call setUpTypeImages), or is automatically shown?

Comment: Both while loading, and once loaded. I add them to choiceLayout after it's initialized to a new GridPane(), so that might be the source of the lag while loading. Not entirely sure about why it's happening after it's loaded.

It's automatically shown as the user starts to run the code. I could comment it out but that's besides the point

Comment: Are you displaying a high number of images at once without using virtualization (ie displaying only those that are in the viewport). If so, this is a common reason of lagging. If the displayed images have a common size are you loading them with that size (thumbnail) or are you loading a much bigger version of the image. I helped build a consumer app that deals with such situations and usually this is the way you handle the problem.

Comment: @AshfakUddn take a look at my answer's comments from Omar. He will guide you better here, and made some suggestions in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Since lag was mentioned I assume there will be many items in this GridPane.

### 1 - Virtualized List

Images are only rendered if and when they are set to appear in the client's viewport (while they are scrolling). This also means if an image was rendered before and it is no longer required then it is best to unload it from memory, if possible (but this adds other complexities). This only makes sense if the user can scroll in one axis which is typically vertical scrolling. This is not a trivial task and you should seek a library that does this for you before trying to do this yourself. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995444/what-are-virtualized-controls-mentioned-in-javafx-documentation) old answer discusses virtualization in JavaFX.

### 2 - Thumbnails

I don't think there was a mention of whether or not the elements would have a fixed size although that is typically the case with grid displays. A good way to reduce the load time is to have a copy of the original image saved somewhere with the dimensions you are planning to display it in so you don't have to load a massive image just to scale it down significantly. It also means it doesn't have to run a resize algorithm for each image to display it.

Comment: Deleted my answer because the mechanism is really different in this world, avoiding possible confussion. This is the answer

Comment: Thank you so much! The virtualization wouldn't have been easy considering how the user can scroll both horizontally and vertically, but resizing the PNG images themselves did the trick. I had no idea resizing images took so much processing power until now

Comment: To be honest not 100% sure about having 2 axis of scrolling for virtualized lists. If you don't need it great. If not I'd do some research. From experience though (unless you find an amazing library) it will lead to lots of edge cases and probably more computational complexity if there's two axes of scrolling.